# Regex Mobile and Phone Number (Singapore standards)

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm not that good when it comes to javascript, and I need to create a regex code for this kind of requirement. Any idea or help will be much appreciate.

Here's the requirement:

1. Should not allow alphabet in phone number OR error message should inform user about it.
2. Phone number needs to be validated according to Singapore standards. Only allow number to start with ""8"" or ""9"" with a maximum of 8 digits."
3. Mobile number needs to be validated according to Singapore standards. Only allow number to start with ""6"" with a maximum of 8 digits."

Comment: have you even searched or tried to build one yourself? There's a whole section for regex here

Comment: Yes @Sagar, I already took a researched on it. Still can't figure out how am I going to start on it since I only have a novice background on javascript, esp. on regex.

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks for that @Sagar. Will try on it.

Answer (score 1):

**For normal phone numbers**

```
(8|9)[0-9]{0,7}
```

- `(8|9)` the number 8 or 9 one time
- `[0-9]{0,7}` **up to** 7 more digits, however I think you didn't mean **max** 7 but **exactly** 7: in that case remove the `0,`

**For mobile phone numbers**

```
 6[0-9]{0,7}
```

- `6` the number 6 one time
- `[0-9]{0,7}` **up to** 7 more digits, however I think you didn't mean **max** 7 but **exactly** 7: in that case remove the `0,`

I have made a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zdAtAo/2) for you